# Unable to access elements in HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

I would like to get an element from an HTMLCollection. The return of document.getElementsByClassName is exactly what I was expecting but when I try to access any attributes of it, it looks like there is nothing there. Here is my code (this code is run in a .js file that I src into my index.html):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var code = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-code');
    console.log(code);
    console.log(code[0]); //undefined
    console.log(code.length); //0
}
```

and here are the console logs :

```
HTMLCollection(1)
   0: div.CodeMirror-code        //this is the div I want to access
   length: 1
   __proto__: HTMLCollection
undefined
0
```

also, If I enter in the console:

```
var code = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-code');
code[0]
```

I get the return:

```
<div class="CodeMirror-code">...</div>
```

which is exactly what I am looking for, but that is not the result I get in the script.

Comment: Or the script is executed before the DOM is fully loaded (script is in the head of the document without attaching DOMContentLoaded event)

Comment: I added a little more context in the question, unfortunately I am building on top of an existing project and I don't know when/how the div is added, but I know that the DOM is loaded because that is when the function is called

Comment: let code = [...code]
Wrap your collection in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror adds it's various DOM elements to the DOM after the `CodeMirror()` constructor is called or after `CodeMirror.fromTextArea()` is called.

So you can't simply wait for the various DOM ready events in order to find the element you are looking for. You can either pass the constructor a function which you can then manually add the editor to the DOM and then do a search. Or setup a custom CodeMirror event listener.

CodeMirror initialization hook

```
CodeMirror.defineInitHook(function(cmInstance){
  var codeDiv = document.querySelector('.CodeMirror-code');
  console.log(codeDiv);
});
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body);
```

CodeMirror manual adding

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(editor){
  //add the editor to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(editor);

  var codeDiv = document.querySelector('.CodeMirror-code');
  //either of these will work
  var codeDiv = editor.querySelector('.CodeMirror-code');

  console.log(codeDiv);
});
```

Demo

```js
CodeMirror.defineInitHook(function(cmInstance){
  DoWork( document.querySelector('.CodeMirror-code') );  
});
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body);

function DoWork(codeDiv){
  console.log(codeDiv);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm just not super familiar with CodeMirror. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be doing this code before the elements have been rendered on the screen. That's why when you do it in the console it works.

Here are two options:

- Try changing the js code to happen `onload` of body. If you don't know what `onload` is check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onload.asp
- Try changing the js code to happen when the `DOMContentLoaded` listener comes up. Learn about how that works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: It is generally better practise to use  DOMContentLoaded event rather than onLoad on your body tag.

Comment: Okay I'll add that.

Comment: @user3210641 That better? Thanks for help!

Comment: I just added more context to the question this code does run on DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Hmm... @EthanHardacre Is the `)` there in the real code?